# Why don't I get the coloring of my source code?

Tags: support

I've used the recommended tag < ! -- etc. for C# but I still don't get the coloring in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130841/how-to-make-an-entity-update-its-own-field). Why?

Answer (score 9):

You [misspelled "language."](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13130841/revisions)

```
<!-- langauge: lang-csharp -->
```

I removed your language spec, and added the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag to your question.  Questions tagged C# are automatically color-coded using the C# coloring, unless you override it.